# How small can an embedded Linux file system get?

Tags: angstrom, root-filesystem

We have an embedded device running the Angstrom distribution - I'm trying to pare down the root file system to as small as possible. I've started by using Narcissus to generate the file system, but the smallest I am getting so far is about 60Mb. Is this the right strategy, or is it worth it to build one from scratch?

Comment: Are you providing your own init?   Do you need to support kernel modules?

Comment: Building from scratch will make more sense. The FS, I created from scratch was just 30 MB with X window system.

Comment: Thanks - I do need to support kernel modules. Right now I am using the a given init - but I am very new at this. Do either of you have a favorite tutorial for building a file system? Leave as an answer and I will close this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the site I ended up using - thanks!

http://buildroot.uclibc.org/